# Running aplications that require the c++ redistributable for Visual Studio 2015

Tags: unity, wine, c++, winetricks

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 .

I can't figure out how to run applications that require the C++ redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 to run.

What do I need to do to run them? I have tried wine and it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

First install winetricks, from a terminal: `sudo apt install winetricks`.
Or, to install the latest one, run:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Winetricks/winetricks/master/src/winetricks
```

Then run `winetricks vcrun2015`.